# How to make a fixed column in Grid Layout?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible? I'm trying to give the right column a fixed attribute, but all the grid goes crazy. I want the right column to remain in the same place, but to maintain its repetitiveness.

My code:

```
<Grid container spacing={30}>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
            <Card>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} style={stylesi.paper}>
          <Paper>
            <Tabs
              value={1}
              indicatorColor="primary"
              textColor="primary"
              centered
            >
              <Tab label="Item One" />
              <Tab label="Item Two" />
              <Tab label="Item Three" />
            </Tabs>
          </Paper>
      </Grid>

      <div style={{position: 'fixed'}}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Card>
               </Card>
            </Grid>
      </div>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What is the `Right Row`? Please give a little more info or a working example maybe?

Comment: The idea is to make a row like Facebook's right column, which always stays at the top of the page even when scrolling down

Comment: :) Its not so . much about the idea behind it, its more about we need to see your css and how it could look, otherwise we've got nothing to go on pal;